# Can I retrieve a dictionary value with a "else key" in a lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

Look this code:

```
arg = 'yes'
(lambda x: dict(yes=1, no=0)[x])(arg)
```

It returns:

```
1
```

But I'd like to return `arg` itself if `arg` is not 'yes' or 'no'.
Something like:

```
arg = 'maybe'
(lambda x: dict(yes=1, no=0, x=x)[x])(arg)
```

I'm getting a error here...

Can I do that? How to do that?

Comment: Why do you even define a `lambda`? Your whole code is just `dict(yes=1, no=0).get(arg, arg)`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, yes, `get` does exactly what I want to do. Ty. But I don't think that is the same question mine. About why lambda, because I want to test applymap method. YET, why down vote everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `lambda` try this:

```
arg = 'maybe'
(lambda x: dict(yes=1, no=0).get(x,x))(arg)
# maybe
```